# How to relaunch a TimerTask

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have written a task to send a certain TCP message through a socket. I have a file with a bunch of messages and some timestamps, so I programmed the task as a TimerTask, and I scheduled it with a Timer with the first message timestamp.

When it finishes, the task run method is over, but its associated thread remains, it's not cancelled. If I try to reschedule the task with a new Time, I'm getting an exception telling me that I cannot reschedulle a schedulled or cancelled task.

I also tried cancellig it before rescheduling, but obviously, as the exception told, it remains the same problem.

I can't schedule the task with a constant perior to let it repeat itself, because each message has a time and it is not constant.

How can I reschedule the TimerTask? And by the way, is there any way of waiting for the task to end, just as in socket communications when it blocks with ready method until a message arrives?

Comment: @pst Indeed, if I do that, it works. But as I have pointed, associated thread remains working even after its run method reaches its end. That means that, when 100 messages have been sent, there are more than 100 threads alive! How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TimerTask is not designed to be rescheduled and it is the Timer that manages the (single) thread.

Use *one* [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and *many* `new` TimerTasks:

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a *single background thread* that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially ..
>
> After the last live reference to a Timer object goes away and all outstanding tasks have completed execution, *the timer's task execution thread [should] terminates gracefully* (and becomes subject to garbage collection).
>
> [From each of the [schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date)) methods:]
>
> *Throws IllegalStateException if [the TimerTask] was already scheduled* or cancelled, timer was cancelled, or timer thread terminated.

If there are indeed many threads spawned by a single Timer, then that *would* be a bug which is unlikely: make sure there really is only one Timer object being used.

The last question, of how to compose individual events into a workflow, should be a separate post.